# Why don't the buttons inside of my $(document).ready(function () call work when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

I have a web page that loads up a table of data. That table is loaded and displayed successfully along with the buttons, however, when I click on button1 or button2, they don't display the alerts and they don't even trip breakpoints that I try to set on the lines. Am I doing this right and my problem is elsewhere or am I just dumb and don't know how to set this up properly?

Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("page is ready");

    initTable();

    $('#button1').click(function () {
        alert("Button 1 clicked!");
    });

    $('#button2').click(function () {
        alert("Button 2 clicked!");
    });

});
```

Attempted setting numerous breakpoints to show the buttons are functional but none are triggered upon clicking the appropriate buttons. Expected alerts to show the content set in the strings. I have checked all of the button ids and they are accurate and the function buttons DO work when the function call is coded directly into the html.

Comment: I'm going to assume that the buttons are added to the DOM BEFORE the table data. Which means the event handler has nothing to attach to. A simple solution is event delegation and use **$(document).on("click","#button2",function () {** instead.

Comment: So scrap the overall $(document).ready() and make individual document calls for each button? or do they go inside of $(document).ready()?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You must use Delegate Event Handlers for elements that do not exist when the page is loaded. See: https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler Also, please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Seems like the comments are assuming that the button isn't actually there at the time you want to add the handler, which means you either need to add the handler later, or use a delegate handler (something like `$(document).on('click', '#button1', function() { ... });`)

You could try adding `console.log($('#button1').length)` to test that, and then know if the button is there when you need it to be, or not.

Comment: Got it! Thank you guys, you were absolutely right. The buttons were not rendered until later due to being apart of an async call. Didn't realize this since it LOOKED like it was being called before. So just simply moving the calls to after the async call returned it worked. I'll try to make a cleaner post if I have any problems in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```
$(function () {
    console.log("page is ready");
    initTable();
    $('table').on("click", "#button1", function () {
        alert("Button 1 clicked!");
    }).on("click", "#button2", function () {
        alert("Button 2 clicked!");
    });
});
```

You may also consider using Classes instead.

```
$(function () {
    console.log("page is ready");
    initTable();
    $('table').on("click", ".remove", function () {
      if(confirm("Are you sure you want to Remove this row?")){
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
      }
    });
});
```

This function would be executed for each `button.remove` in the table.

> **Delegated event handlers** have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated event handlers to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

See More: https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler